# Why is my Email not sending anymore

Tags: php, laravel-4, amazon-ec2, cron

> Server: Amazon ec2 Linux
>
> Framework: Laravel 4.2

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

           \Mail::send( 'emails.plain.plain', array('body' => 'woo'), function ($sendemail)  {
                $sendemail->subject ( "subject" );
                $sendemail->from( 'from@ymail.com', 'From Name' );
                $sendemail->to( 'to@gmail.com', 'To Name' );
            } ); 

?>
```

Here's what happened, I sent 1000 emails to my inbox because of Cron Job sending every minute.

Now I'm not receiving any emails.

Comment: Well, 1000 emails? No wonder your emails get blocked by the provider. :-)

Comment: also you have exceed limit :D

Comment: @CharlotteDunois The gmail provider and yahoo provider? But if I send message via gmail.com, I received it.

Comment: @Noman What is the solution for this? How do I reset my limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been throttled by AWS.

Read up on the documentation for limits of AWS services: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

Comment: I don't understand the documentation of AWS, Can you explain it for me?

Comment: @BazzBee, you've just sent to many e-mails which exceeded your allowed limit and now you're not allowed to send any more mails. As simple as that.

Comment: What is the solution for this? How do I reset my limit?

Comment: Contact AWS support; you're probably blocked because of abuse.